# What is the use of persistData() method in Zend_Form()

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am creating form, i found some method called `persistData()`.

I have explored the Zend_Form class but there is no documentation.

I ams curious about its usefulness. Can anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: Can you show us the function?

Comment: empty, just  public function persistData()
    {
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function - is part of plans for future functionality.

The plan was to use it for persisting data in the session between requests 
-- which would be useful for multi-page forms. But it was a low priority 
feature, so developer placed a stub only; there's also a test marked incomplete 
for it in the test suite.

[PROOF LINK](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Form-isErrors-td667975.html)

Comment: Hi Bogdan, Thanks for your answer..now i'm understand..it helps me because i dont want to use it incorrectly :).